# PHP Best practice for saving/storing very small amounts of data

Tags: php, storage, store

What I'm doing currently *works* but I just have the feeling that there's a better way, or perhaps a more professional way to do it. I'm talking about very small amounts of data, like one number (or a few numbers) that is saved so as to store the selection made in a drop down list so its remembered every time the page is re-opened. I'm not using a mysql database at all so its all saved to file only.

Right now I simply save the number to a text file to save the selected folder, and then have several other numbers underneath it to save the selected files. All selected from drop down lists like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="text">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="first">first</option>
<option value="second">second</option>
<option value="etc">etc</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Then they are stored in a text file that simply looks like this:

```
7
4
3
```

When the folder or file is altered the change is made with the following code:

```
function saveFile($line,$data,$savepath) {
$trace=file($savepath);$trace[$line]=$data;
file_put_contents($savepath,$trace);
}

if(isset($_POST['text'])) {
$changed=$_POST['text'];
saveFile($selected,$changed."\n",$savepath);
}
```

The code chooses which line of the text file to save to. Maybe there is a much better way or something completely different? Although I don't want to use sql or anything like that.

Comment: If it works for you, then why not? Usually you should store data into databases

Comment: Best practice is a DB/SQL.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use SQL or similar?  This is whole point of databases

Comment: I think you can try something like mongoDB.

Comment: @bub Yeah it works but recently I asked a question about something and was told I was doing it all wrong and so ended up changing my code completely. There's often a better way to do things. Although for just about 10 or so numbers it seems a bit of a hassle and unecessary to have a database set up. My idea of sql is to have at least 100s but often thousands or more items of data with many elements in each particle, like name, address, phone number etc for each element. My need is just for individual digits alone and only about 10 in total...

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of downvotes for ignoring the following point:

> Although I don't want to use sql or anything like that

You don't need to run a huge database system for this.  Something along the lines of [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) lets you have the functionality of the database, without huge overheads.  The SQLite database is essentially a specific type of file with all of the relationships you configure, but gives a bit more flexibility than a flat file structure you're working with.

Comment: I don't think you deserve downvotes as this solution doesn't use a regular database, SQLite is a flat file database which is not on the same level as regular databases like mysql, and it works very well for small applications.

Comment: Is it worth setting up a database just for storing about 10 numbers though?

Comment: @Hasen If those numbers can change and therefore can't be coded into your application, then yes.  You never know when you might want to store more information, or work with it differently.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks you are attempting to persist few values from page load to page load. If this is only needed in the UI and not on the server-side I would save the data in a cookie ,but this is a rather dated solution to the problem ,also using local storage should do the trick for you. Sorry for the JavaScript solution and not PHP. Sample code:

localStorage.setItem("attr", "value");

alert( "attr: " + localStorage.getItem("attr"));

Comment: _Sorry for the JavaScript solution and not PHP..._ sorry but OP asked for php and not JavaScript

Comment: Yeah I normally use local storage with javascript but I don't think PHP has that.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to save your data parsed as Json, serialized (associative) array or similar to a file. That way you have named values and you know what value belongs to what function in your system if you open that file again in two years.

But again, if that hugely increases the complexity of your project or it begins to stop being efficient (because of the great amount of stored values), an optimised database, like others already recommended, would be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

To save small amounts of data like this to file, I would recommend storing the data as key/value pairs in an array and then either serialize the array (or convert it to JSON) and then save that.

E.g.

```
$folderValue = 5;
$file1Value = 6;
$file2Value = 7;

/**
  * Saving data
  */
$data = array(
    'folder' => $folderValue,
    'file1' => $file1Value,
    'file2' => $file2Value,
);

file_put_contents($filename , serialize(data));


/**
  * Getting data (this will be the same array you
  * saved to file at an earlier point) which you can
  * iterate over or grab values via key.
  */

$data = unserialize(file_get_contents($filename));

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo "key {$key} is {$value}\n";
    // e.g. "key folderValue is 5";
}

echo $data['folder'] . "\n";
// e.g. "5";
```

SQL is still a better candidate for storing application state.  Flat files are poor because they become difficult to manage over time, but if you do use files, a key=>value mapping is important for readability.

SQLite could be a good candidate if you need a low overhead SQL (low configuration, no background server running), but it has its own limitations (low performance, doesn't scale).

PHP has good documentation around serializing data:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Json is another good format for data serialization.  Also see json_encode and json_decode.

Comment: serialize seems to turn the data into a big mess? Its all i:8;s:3:"Name";i:9; etc.  How do you store the value for any single item then? I mean the number that is associated with the relevant folder?

Comment: Thanks, you gave me some good ideas. I used var_export in the end and its really much better this way and uses less code overall.

Comment: You always use the unserialize function on serialized data.  Serialized data isn't meant to be used directly.  I would suggest putting all your values into an array array first so that you can apply a key to each value (i.e. a label) so your code is more readable.  The serialize function is a way to convert a complex data structure (e.g. arrays, objects) into a string so they can be stored or transmitted easily.  Unserialize will take that string and rebuild the data as it existed before.

Comment: Ok I see. Yes I converted it into an array first but sometimes if something is up its advisable to look at the saved data file directly. With serialise it was too much of a mess to see what was wrong. With var_export it stored the data very neatly and any problems if data was saved incorrectly for example and needed to be changed directly, I could easily find it by opening the saved file and looking at it. var_export seemed to do the exact same thing as serialize, except it stored just the array data itself without adding all kinds of other junk in with it.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Rocket-Store](https://packagist.org/packages/paragi/rocket-store)...